# Timer in UpdatePanel

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel, timer, master-pages

I have an asp:UpdatePanel with an asp:Timer.  These are in a Master/Content Page.  The code is below:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="5000" OnTick="Timer1_Tick"></asp:Timer>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

But when the timer fires, I get the folowing error:

Microsoft JScript runtime error: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: The message received from the server could not be parsed. Common causes for this error are when the response is modified by calls to Response.Write(), response filters, HttpModules, or server trace is enabled.
Details: Error parsing near '

This works in a standalone web form, but not in a content page with a master page.

Can anyone explain a fix for this?

Thanks in advance for any help!!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Is there a specifc reason why you have the `Timer` control in the `UpdatePanel`?

Every time I have needed to use a `Timer` control to cause an `UpdatePanel` refresh, I have set it up like the following and it works fine with `MasterPages`:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional"> 
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger  ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate> 
        <!-- your content here, no timer -->
    </ContentTemplate> 
</asp:UpdatePanel> 

<asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="5000" OnTick="Timer1_Tick">
</asp:Timer>
```

Use the `Trigger` to cause the `UpdatePanel` to refresh from the `Tick` event.  You only want to embed content in your `UpdatePanel` if possible.

Comment: Actually, I had that exact code and it was not working either... BUT, you made me look elsewhere, and I relaized I had this in my PageLoad:

Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-1));
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
Response.Cache.SetNoStore();

And that appears to be the problem... commented those out and it works perfectly.

Thank you your info.