# Running back ground action

Tags: asp.net

I need some thing like sending SMS to inactive users. If some user is inactive for 36hrs he much get a text saying `you are away from this site` To do this how an ASP.NET page fires the query for every 3 minutes to check for the new user's inactivity in database.

I have a code to perform the query. I need how in ASP.NET to run query for every 3 minutes without opening browser. Do ASCX file does my work? or should I use something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Timer control for this
[Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3523470/timer-in-updatepanel)

and in page load you can send the code if your update panel has updated

Comment: Is there no other way than using Page_Load function.

Comment: You can use in javascript calling one function.and in the page load we can use if (!ispostback)