# How to next page number in gridview every 1 minute with code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I try to refresh page with timer every 1 minute and display data in gridview on next page until last record.
What should I do?

```
protect void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
   if(GridView1.PageIndex==GridView.PageCount)
   {
      GridView1.PageIndex=1;
   } 
   else 
   {  int pageno = GridView1.PageIndex+1; 
      GridView1.PageIndex=pageno;
   } 
   GridView1.DataBind(); Timer1.Interval=600000;
}
```

Comment: you understand difference between c# code behind and final html/js?

Comment: That will not work.  Your timer is running at the server.  The client is just sitting there not requesting anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`PageIndex` is zero-based index  and `PageCount` is calculated by dividing the total number of records in the data source by the number of records displayed in a page (as specified by the PageSize property) and rounding up.

so `PageIndex` will never equal to `PageCount`

```
if(GridView1.PageIndex == (GridView1.PageCount -1))
{
   GridView1.PageIndex = 0;
}
else
{
   GridView1.PageIndex = GridView1.PageIndex + 1;
}
GridView1.DataBind();
```

You can use Ajax Update panel and put your grid inside the panel. Then you can use above code inside the`OnTick` event of `Timer` which set as `AsyncPostBackTrigger`, check below SO question for example

[Timer in UpdatePanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3523470/timer-in-updatepanel)

Comment: I see. How to display next page in gridview?