# Update DataList with update panel

Tags: asp.net

i have problem when i try to update my `DataList` with `UpdatePanel` without refresh page, i use timer for `AsyncPostBackTriggers`:

this is my script

```
<asp:Timer runat="server" ID="Timer1" Interval="3000" OnTick="OnTimer" />
   <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UP1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
      <ContentTemplate>
         <asp:DataList ID="DS1" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblC" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Country") %>'/>
            </ItemTemplate>
         </asp:DataList>
      </ContentTemplate>
      <Triggers>
         <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="TimerCon" EventName="Tick"/>
      </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

and this is my Code

```
protected void OnTimer(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Country, Status FROM Customer", con);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    da.Fill(ds);
    DS1.DataSource = ds;
    DS1.DataBind();
    con.Close();
}
```

i have 2 `DataList`and i just want to update one `DataList`
so when `Triggers` is on just updated 1 `DataList` and not refreshed whole page

when i remove the triggers tag from code my datalist update also my page is reloaded
what i need is my datalist update but my page is not reload

Comment: What is `DSContainer`?

Comment: sorry my bad...i already edited

Comment: look here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc295400.aspx

Comment: similar post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3523470/timer-in-updatepanel

Comment: What _is_ the problem you have? You haven't mentioned it. If you remove the trigger the whole page refreshes what you don't want. But why do you want to remove it then?

Comment: i have 2 DataList and i just want to update one datalist
so when triggers is on just updated 1 DataList and not refreshed whole page