# asp.net timer not firing the updatepanel

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a table within my aspx page content page (using a Master Page also)
The problem is the Timer doesn't seem to be doing the async postback it doesnt even hit the method
I've tried a fresh solution in VS with the below code and it works fine every 10 seconds the event updatepanel is refreshed.  So I believe the code is fine but there's something stopping this from working and I can't figure what.

```
   <div class="row" >


                    <div class="col-md-3">

                        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
                            <asp:Triggers>
                                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="TimerPrayer"></asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger>

                            </asp:Triggers>

                            <ContentTemplate>
                                <table id="tblPrayerTimes" class="table-condensed">
                                    <tr>
                                        <th colspan="3">

                                            <asp:Label ID="LblPrayer" runat="server" CssClass="prayerTimeHeaderscss" Text="Prayer Time"></asp:Label>
                                        </th>
                                        <th colspan="1">
                                            <asp:Label ID="lblJammat" runat="server" CssClass="prayerTimeHeaderscss" Text="Jamaat Time"></asp:Label>
                                        </th>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td></td>

                                        <th>
                                            <asp:Label ID="lblToday" runat="server" CssClass="prayerlabeltodaytomorrowcss" Text="Today"></asp:Label>
                                        </th>

                                        <th>
                                            <asp:Label ID="lblTomorrow" runat="server" CssClass="prayerlabeltodaytomorrowcss" Text="Tomorrow"></asp:Label>
                                        </th>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:Label ID="lblFajr" runat="server" CssClass="prayerLabelscss" Text="Fajr"></asp:Label>
                                        </td>
                                        <td style="text-align: center">
                                            <asp:Label ID="lblbegFajrTime" runat="server" CssClass="prayerTimescss" Text="00:00"></asp:Label>
                                        </td>
                                        <td style="text-align: center">
                                            <asp:Label ID="lbltmrwFajrTime" runat="server" CssClass="prayerTimeTmrwcss" Text="00:00"></asp:Label>
                                        </td>
                                        <td id="tdfajrJamaatbox" style="text-align: center">
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtFajrJamaat" runat="server" Text="00:00" onmousedown="displayPicker('Fajr','tdfajrJamaatbox');" MaxLength="5" CssClass="prayerTimeJamaat"></asp:TextBox>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:Label ID="lblSunrise" runat="server" CssClass="prayerLabelscss" Text="Sunrise"></asp:Label>
                                        </td>
                                        <td style="text-align: center">
                                            <asp:Label ID="lblbegSunRiseTime" runat="server" CssClass="prayerTimescss" Text="00:00"></asp:Label>
                                        </td>
                                        <td style="text-align: center">
                                            <asp:Label ID="lbltmrwSunriseTime" runat="server" CssClass="prayerTimeTmrwcss" Text="00:00"></asp:Label>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:Label ID="lblDkubra" runat="server" CssClass="prayerLabelscss" Text="Dahawa Kubra"></asp:Label>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:Label ID="lblDkubraTime" runat="server" CssClass="prayerTimescss" Text="00:00"></asp:Label>
                                        </td>
                                        <td style="text-align: center"></td>
                                        <td id="td1" style="text-align: center"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:Label ID="lblDhuhr" runat="server" CssClass="prayerLabelscss" Text="Dhuhr"></asp:Label>
                                        </td>
                                        <td style="text-align: center">
                                            <asp:Label ID="lblbegDhuhrTime" runat="server" CssClass="prayerTimescss" Text="00:00"></asp:Label>
                                        </td>


                                        <td style="text-align: center">
                                            <asp:Label ID="lbltmrwDhuhrTime" runat="server" CssClass="prayerTimeTmrwcss" Text="00:00"></asp:Label>
                                        </td>
                                        <td id="tddhuhrJamaatbox" style="text-align: center">
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtDhuhrJamaat" runat="server" CssClass="prayerTimeJamaat" Text="00:00" onmousedown="displayPicker('Dhuhr','tddhuhrJamaatbox');" MaxLength="5"></asp:TextBox>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:Label ID="lblAsr" runat="server" CssClass="prayerLabelscss" Text="Asr"></asp:Label>
                                        </td>
                                        <td style="text-align: center">
                                            <asp:Label ID="lblbegAsrTime" runat="server" CssClass="prayerTimescss" Text="00:00"></asp:Label>
                                        </td>
                                        <td style="text-align: center">
                                            <asp:Label ID="lbltmrwAsrTime" runat="server" CssClass="prayerTimeTmrwcss" Text="00:00"></asp:Label>
                                        </td>
                                        <td id="tdasrJamaatbox" style="text-align: center">
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtAsrJamaat" runat="server" CssClass="prayerTimeJamaat" Text="00:00" onmousedown="displayPicker('Asr','tdasrJamaatbox');" MaxLength="5"></asp:TextBox>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:Label ID="lblMaghrib" runat="server" CssClass="prayerLabelscss" Text="Maghrib"></asp:Label>
                                        </td>
                                        <td style="text-align: center">
                                            <asp:Label ID="lblbegMaghribTime" runat="server" CssClass="prayerTimescss" Text="00:00"></asp:Label>
                                        </td>
                                        <td style="text-align: center">
                                            <asp:Label ID="lbltmrwMaghrib" runat="server" CssClass="prayerTimeTmrwcss" Text="00:00"></asp:Label>
                                        </td>
                                        <td id="tdmaghribJamaatbox" style="text-align: center">
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtMaghribJamaat" runat="server" CssClass="prayerTimeJamaat" Text="00:00" onmousedown="displayPicker('Maghrib','tdmaghribJamaatbox');" MaxLength="5"></asp:TextBox>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:Label ID="lblIsha" runat="server" CssClass="prayerLabelscss" Text="Isha"></asp:Label>
                                        </td>
                                        <td style="text-align: center">
                                            <asp:Label ID="lblbegIshaTime" runat="server" CssClass="prayerTimescss" Text="00:00"></asp:Label>
                                        </td>
                                        <td style="text-align: center">
                                            <asp:Label ID="lbltmrwIshaTime" runat="server" CssClass="prayerTimeTmrwcss" Text="00:00"></asp:Label>
                                        </td>
                                        <td id="tdishaJamaatbox" style="text-align: center">
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtIshaJamaat" runat="server" CssClass="prayerTimeJamaat" Text="00:00" onmousedown="displayPicker('Isha','tdishaJamaatbox');" MaxLength="5"></asp:TextBox>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>

                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:Label ID="lblJamaat" runat="server" CssClass="prayerLabelscss" Text="Jummah 1"></asp:Label>
                                        </td>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td id="tdjummah1Jamaatbox" style="text-align: center">
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtJummah1Jamaat" runat="server" CssClass="prayerTimeJamaat" Text="13:30" onmousedown="displayPicker('Jummah1','tdjummah1Jamaatbox');" MaxLength="5"></asp:TextBox>
                                        </td>

                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:Label ID="lblJummah2" runat="server" CssClass="prayerLabelscss" Text="Jummah 2"></asp:Label>
                                        </td>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td id="tdjummah2Jamaatbox" style="text-align: center">
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtJummah2Jamaat" runat="server" CssClass="prayerTimeJamaat" Text="13:30" onmousedown="displayPicker('Jummah2','tdjummah2Jamaatbox');" MaxLength="5"></asp:TextBox>
                                        </td>

                                    </tr>

                                    <tr>
                                        <td colspan="4">
                                            <asp:Button ID="btnRadioStatus" OnClick="btnRadioStatus_Click" runat="server" Enabled="false" CssClass="cssRadioStatus"
                                                Text="Button" />

                                        </td>


                                    </tr>

                                </table>
                                </ContentTemplate>
                            </asp:UpdatePanel>



                        <asp:Timer ID="TimerPrayer" runat="server" OnTick="TimerPrayer_Tick" Interval="10000"></asp:Timer>


                    </div>
```

code behind

```
protected void TimerPrayer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ReadMyData();

}
```

Comment: I've been working with these lately, and I noticed mine failed as well if I had the timer doing too much work. I was having it check for a file existing and some other stuff at most it should set a couple quick variables and force a refresh.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I put a timer inside my update panel. It was not firing its OnTick event callback at all.
I moved the timer outside the update panel and then it started firing on the callback.
Then I added a Trigger for the timer in the update panel and it works:

```xml
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanelChart" runat="server">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="tmChartPanel" 
            EventName="Tick" />
    </Triggers>
    <!-- ... -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use trigger.Because update panel postback works with [trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/aspnet-ajax/understanding-asp-net-ajax-updatepanel-triggers).

You don't have to use timer in update panel,use timer outside the update panel.
And as an example using timer in update panel

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional"> 
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger  ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate> 
        <!-- your content here, no timer -->
    </ContentTemplate> 
</asp:UpdatePanel> 

<asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="5000" OnTick="Timer1_Tick">
</asp:Timer>
```

source of [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3523470/timer-in-updatepanel)

Answer (score 0):

I had this in my page load which was stopping the postback

```
 ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "setDOM", "$(\"#divDigitalClock\").clock({ \"langSet\":\"en\",\"format\":\"24\"});", true);
```