# UpdatePanel from Page_Load without postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, async-await, updatepanel

I created an ASP .NET Web Forms application from Visual Studio 2017 creator with C# as a language. I did minimum changes to the template and my web page loads a 3D image, takes a few additional parameters via Buttons and Text fields, sends it for processing to server. There it lands in a directory where it is processed by a commercial program, independent of Visual Studio, which initially writes to a directory with an image ID (say ABCD) and into a directory with an image taking date (say 20170629), after some processing, 2-5 minutes, it writes the results of the analysis into a new folder with a current date (say 20171031) into a text file where the name consists of 15 digits code and a known extension (say 123456789012345.txt). It is within Java Derby database, for which I did not find any connectors from .NET.

The web page meanwhile shows the summary of data sent. What I got working is the Button which while pressed checks if the mentioned directory (20171031) is already created shows the asp:UpdatePanel with progress (1/3 stages passed, 2/3 stages passed etc.) and when the file 123456789012345.txt is ready it gets the data from it and on the server side it calculates some values and displays them. Because of waiting there are several public async Task and public async Task methods to search for file appearance.

**I wanted to avoid manual pressing of the Button**, so that the processing stage is shown and once the file 123456789012345.txt is ready the values is calculated. For the moment I tried various ways, but without success. I prefer to avoid reloading the whole page every 30 seconds, because the user may get confused.

asp:UpdatePanel, as far as I understand needs pressing of the Button or some other interaction from the user side. If I use in aspx.cs file in Load_Page method the UpdatePanelName.Update(); for whatever reason the panel is not updated. Due to the use of await CalculateImageAsync(), the only way I found to have it in Page__Load is to have it as protected async void Page_Load(object sender, EventArg e) , but when page is loaded, it never loads. Anything else needs user interaction, which I want to avoid. I got stuck...

I am new in ASP .NET and C#, so maybe I do something wrong or miss some nice .NET method. I would be obliged for help. I have seen pages doing the job like I want, for example in the journals, where you submit a DOCX file where it is converted to PDF - once you submit it after some time you get a page with resulting PDF.

Regards, Marcin

Comment: UpdatePanels will always cause a postback. There's no way around that. You can choose what logic to execute during a postback if you need to.

Comment: I know, my point is how to update a panel from the server side without user interacting with the page... Marcin

Comment: Well there's always a [Timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3523470/timer-in-updatepanel)....but really, UpdatePanel is terrible and you should avoid it like the plague. You'll be far better of either implementing server side push (such as [SignalR](https://www.asp.net/signalr)) or using AJAX techniques.