# how to auto refresh time on asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

hey guys i want to auto refresh my time,so the current page is displaying actual date and time,but if the time in our computer increase,the time that displayed on the web does not,so i have to refresh the page with refresh button to get an actual time again,so how can i get auto refreshed time but without refreshing the page ? here is my code bellow

```
<--! language : c# -->

public partial class MasterPage : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dateLabel.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
        timeLabel.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:tt");

    }
}
```

Comment: Is it the server time that you need?

Comment: i need the actual time,like the time on our laptop,it's auto refresh right

Answer (score 0):

You have some options:

- If you are using asp.net webforms, take a look at this questions about update panel and triggers: [Timer in UpdatePanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3523470/timer-in-updatepanel)
- you can do it using javascript to keep your clock ‘running’, starting in your first get and then Js.
- more advanced scenario, using signalr, https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1102221/Real-Time-Clock-using-SignalR

Good luck!