# How to use UpdatePanel to refresh value in ASP

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have Asp Chart control in `C#` that set the `<asp:Title Text=` value in `HTML` :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
    ...
    WriteChart1();
}

public void WriteChart1(){
       ...
           Chart1.Titles[1].Text = res_NoDown;         //<-- res_NoDown is a string
           Chart1.Titles[1].ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Lime;
           Chart1.DataSource = ds;
           Chart1.Series[0].XValueMember = "Down_Time_Class"; 
           Chart1.Series[0].YValueMembers = "qty"; 
           Chart1.Titles[0].Text = res_ReasonDay;      //<-- res_ReasonDay is a string
    }
```

My `HTML` is like below:

```
  <div class="block1">

      <asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server" BackColor="Black" BackImageTransparentColor="Black" Height="160px" Width="500px">
          <Titles>
              <asp:Title Name="Title1" Text="Title1" Alignment="TopCenter" BackImageAlignment="Top">
              </asp:Title>
              <asp:Title Name="Title2">
              </asp:Title>
          </Titles>
      </asp:Chart>

  </div>
```

The `Text` value in `<asp:Title>` above is using the value from Asp chart control in `C#`, and this value, `res_NoDown;` is not fixed and sometimes different.

Before this, I use `Response.AddHeader("Refresh", "60");` and it refresh the whole page in order the value in `<asp:Title>` to change. But I dont want to refresh the whole page.

What I want to achieve is I want to refresh only `<asp:Chart1>` section every 60 seconds in order to change the `Text` value in `<asp:Title>` following the `res_NoDown` value in `C#` .

I read that I can use `UpdatePanel` to achieve this, but Im stucked as Im not familiar with `ASP`.

**What I have done so far is this**, but when it refresh, its not getting the value from `C#, res_NoDown`, instead it show the value that is set on it: `Text="Title1"`.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="Script1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>

  <div class="block1">

      <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
          <ContentTemplate>
             <asp:Timer runat="server" OnTick="Page_Load" Interval="60000"></asp:Timer>

      <asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server" BackColor="Black" BackImageTransparentColor="Black" Height="160px" Width="500px">
          <Titles>
              <asp:Title Name="Title1" Text="Title1" Alignment="TopCenter" BackImageAlignment="Top">
              </asp:Title>
              <asp:Title Name="Title2">
              </asp:Title>
          </Titles>
      </asp:Chart>

              </ContentTemplate>
      </asp:UpdatePanel>
  </div>
```

Hope I've explained my problem very clearly. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: possible duplicate -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3523470/timer-in-updatepanel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The update panel needs a trigger for it to update the content within its `ContentTemplate`.

Basically the `UpdatePanel` updates the content within `ContentTemplate` when any of the following occurs:

```
1. Postback event triggered by controls with "`AutoPostBack=True`" inside the `ContentTemplate`.
2. The Update Panel's `Trigger` was triggered.
```

For your case, you want the Chart to be refreshed every 60 seconds. Thus, your trigger would be time-based. Hence a `Timer` will be needed as your `Trigger`.

Someone has asked this question before and it was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3523470/timer-in-updatepanel). You may refer to the solution and see if it solves your problem.

Comment: Actually, u can see that I did put a `Timer` already at code above. It did trigger the `UpdatePanel` but the `<asp:Title Text=` value is not getting from `C#`. Instead it show the value set on it that is, `Text="Title1"` . How can I make it get this value from `C#` ? `Chart1.Titles[1].Text = res_NoDown;`